# Subdirectories configuration Apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, subdomain

I am currently setting up a website on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2.4.

What I am trying to do is restrict HTTP(S) access to my subdomains to certain IPs.
Those subdomains are either used for development tests or are admin tools (phpMyAdmin, etc.), so I definitely don't want those subdomains to be public.
I also want domain.com to be public.

**What is the current state of the website:**

- domain.com is publicly accessible
- domain.com is showing /var/www/html/ content
- sub1.domain.com is publicly accessible
- sub1.domain.com is showing /var/www/html/sub1 content
- sub2.domain.com is publicly accessible
- sub2.domain.com is showing /var/www/html/sub2 content

**What is the expected result:**

- domain.com is publicly accessible
- sub1.domain.com is restricted to several IPs
- sub2.domain.com is restricted to several IPs

This is my configuration so far:

DNS entries:

```
Name   Type   TTL  Target
        A     300  ServerIP
sub1   CNAME  300  domain.com
sub2   CNAME  300  domain.com
www    CNAME  300  domain.com
```

apache2.conf:

```
[...]
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/sub1>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
[...]
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub1.domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub1
    <Directory /var/www/html/sub1>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub1.domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Symbolic links are made from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub*.domain.com.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Something I also don't understand is if I try to add a .htaccess file in `/var/www/html/php56`, it isn't taken into account, despite the `AllowOverride All`

Another thing I am trying to do, is to redirect domain.com/sub1 requests to sub1.domain.com instead of throwing a 403 error, but without a .htaccess file, so I minimize the number of config files.

**Note: For testing purposes, I intentionally set `Require all denied` instead of `Require ip x.x.x.x`**

What I am doing wrong?

If I forgot to provide any required info, please let me know.

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Tom's advice, I figured out what was wrong.
In my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub1.domain.com.conf` I had a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. Actually, Let's Encrypt created a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub1.domain.com-le-ssl.conf` file (during the certificate setup, I chose to force HTTPS redirection), and in that file there were `Require all granted` so, that file was overwriting my `sub1.domain.com.conf` file.

Finally, I changed my directories setup according to Tom's answer - much clearer that way, thanks!
It also solved my redirection question, as now my root folder for domain.com is `/var/www/domain.com/www`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not make the root directory of the subdomain a subfolder of the root domain. Instead of:

```
/var/www/html/
    - sub1/
    - sub2/
    - sub3/
```

I would do it myself like this:

```
/var/www/domain.com/
    - www/ (the root)
    - sub1/
    - sub2/
    - sub3/
```

This makes it a lot easier to limit access to files. In your current setup, perhaps access is limited by a `VirtualHost` but the same data can be accessed by going via the root domain: `http://www.example.com/sub1/data`.